# How to horizontally center a div with anchor links inside?

Tags: html, css

I've looked into this and follow a couple instructions and they don't seem to work.

Follow this link for the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/3h937r1q/7/

I've tried `margin: 0 auto;`(`center-block` class) and `float: none;` on the parent div but I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help me center div in the middle of the page and tell me why it isn't working?

Expected outcome: https://jsfiddle.net/3h937r1q/22/

Except I do not want to use `margin-left` to move it in to the middle

Comment: Can you please provide some part of the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @AlbanianGamerYT If you follow the jsfiddle you'll see the code

Comment: You mean vertical centering?

Comment: @adamk22 Horizontal

Comment: this is already in center. you want vertically center?

Comment: @SagarKodte Apologies! I've updated my question, I would like to center the div

Comment: This is what I see: http://imgur.com/VJE1lbz 

It's horzintally centered, but not vertically.

Comment: i only saw you link

Comment: Makes more sense now haha

Comment: @SagarKodte + adamk22 : Sorry guys!

Comment: we're not getting what do you want

Comment: @SagarKodte I would like to center the div in the middle of the page, so you two anchor links are directly in the center of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use col-offset:

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 home-buttons center-block" >
        <a href="#" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 HomepageBtn Animate col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-4" >
            <div class="tile-text">
                AP REVIEW
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 HomepageBtn Animate">
            <div class="tile-text">
                VAT CHECKER
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Thanks, I know but I would like to center it in the page. Using offset doesn't center it in the page for me. It's just moves it closer to the middle

Comment: screen is divided in 12 cols...so suppose u have 2 cols with 4 and 4 length....remaining length is 4 so u need to give offset of 2 to align them in center...

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I've used this before and it doesn't always give me the expected results

Comment: It's just because I also have other things on the page which causes it to screw up. I'll just make a work around

Answer (score 0):

I have removed `height` and given `padding: 40px 0px` to `anchor` tag

[**Updated DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/3h937r1q/16/)

```
.home-buttons .HomepageBtn {
  background-color: #4F7F64;
  /*height: 140px;*/
  padding: 40px 0px;
  color: white;
  font-size: small;
  font-family: "futura-pt-n7", 'futura-pt', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for this! I've updated my question, I meant center the div and not the text.

Comment: Add expected output image in your quest it will be more helpful.

Comment: If you can give `width` you have have style. Check it https://jsfiddle.net/3h937r1q/24/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this. As you are using bootstrap grid in within **a** tag, you must use bootstrap offset class to center the element.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 home-buttons">
    <a href="#" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-2 HomepageBtn Animate">
        <div class="tile-text">
        AP REVIEW
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 HomepageBtn Animate">
        <div class="tile-text">
        VAT CHECKER
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/25Lno6n7/

```
.home-buttons {
  width:600px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
   }

   .home-buttons .HomepageBtn {
     flex:0 0 300px;
   }
```